# (Complicated) RAID hard drive issue

Tags: linux, partition, raid, mdadm, synology

I have a (complicated) RAID hard drive issue:

I have a Synology DS413j with 4 hds, hd 3 failed so I decided to replace them. The official support article says to replace them one by one, and being the dumb person I am I replaced hard drive 1. I then decided to transfer the files onto a external hard drive then create a new volume with the new hds and then transfer the files back on, but then hd 3 kept on crashing the entire thing, and with hard drive 1 not being initialized and SHR's one drive fault tolerance, I couldn't do that successfully without multiple attempts. I now pulled all 4 hds and decided to create a new volume with the new drives then take the 4 old hds and transfer the data that way. When I put the SHR formatted hds on gparted it looks like this:

> /dev/sdc1 - Linux-Raid-Member (2,5GB)
>
> /dev/sdc2 - Linux-Raid-Member (2,5GB)
>
> Unallocated Space
>
> /dev/sdc3 - Extended (2,0TB)
>
> ```
> Unallocated Space
> /dev/sdc5 - Linux-Raid-Member (2,0TB)
> Unallocated Space
> ```

*fdisk -l* says:

> Disk /dev/sde: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
>
> Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
>
> Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>
> I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>
> Disklabel type: dos
>
> Disk identifier: 0x48da305a
>
> Device     Boot   Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
>
> /dev/sde1           256    4980735    4980480  2.4G fd Linux raid
>   autodetect
>
> /dev/sde2       4980736    9175039    4194304    2G fd Linux raid
>   autodetect
>
> /dev/sde3       9437184 3907015007 3897577824  1.8T  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
>
> /dev/sde5       9453280 3907015007 3897561728  1.8T fd Linux raid
>   autodetect

sdc1 & sdc2 are probably the system partitions (which have been corrupted on 2 of the hds), sdc5 is the data.

Any ideas on how to tackle this?

Comment: "The official support article says to replace them one by one" -- I expect that the official support article expects that you know you only need to replace the failing drive. Additionally the output of `fdisk -l` is probably more useful than what you've pasted.

Comment: I wanted to replace all the drives, so according to the support article I need to replace them one by one. Will add fdisk -l soon.